# discord.py button disabled with variables

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm developing discord.py bot. I wanna disabled the button when condition is True. How can I do that?

Here's my code

```
from discord import ui, app_commands, Interaction
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        await tree.sync()
        print(f"{self.user} on")

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)


class bigView(ui.View):

    def __init__(self,a:int,b:int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @ui.button(label="yes",disabled= self.a>self.b) # here
    async def yes(interaction:Interaction, button:ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="yes a is bigger than b")

@tree.command(name="big", description="big")
async def big(interaction:Interaction,a:int,b:int):
   await interaction.response.send_message(view=bigView(a,b))

client.run(token)
```

That code isn't work. Can I get a variables like self.a or whatever?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I just wanna button disabled with variables but I can't use self in @ui.button. How can I do get True or False to variables?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add buttons dynamically. Then, you would be able to easily access variables from self.

```py
class bigView(ui.View):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.add_buttons()
    def add_buttons(self):
        yes_button = ui.Button(label='yes', disabled=self.a > self.b)

        async def yes(interaction: Interaction, button: ui.Button):
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content="yes a is bigger than b")

        yes_button.callback = yes
        self.add_item(yes_button)

@tree.command(name="big", description="big")
async def big(interaction:Interaction, a: int, b: int):
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=bigView(a, b))
```

It is important to note that you have to set you button's `callback` to you callback function and
add it to the view with `add_item`. This `add_buttons` function is then called in `__init__`

Comment: that code is not readable, but it works. thx